# How can I recover data in a cell of my table (saved as an array)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I save the rights of my users in my database as a table array

```
user    user_right (varchar 255) 

1       ["write","delete"]
2       ["write","delete","update"]
3       ["add","write","delete"]
4       ["write"]
```

I would like to know how to list the data that is in the `user_right` column?

```
select ... from users where id = 1
```

Have a list that looks like this

```
write
delete
```

Comment: you've got this problem because your data is not stored in a normalised form, it's not inherently suited to a SQL query. Each cell in your table should only ever store a single value. What you really want is a separate "user_rights" table which has a foreign key back to the users table, such that you can list each right in a separate row, with a reference back to the user ID it belongs to. Then you can have multiple rights per user very easily, and query them very easily to get a list. If you haven't studied relational database design before, now would be a good time to start.

Comment: It's not a solution to your current problem but a proper way to safe those data is with another table and for each new right a new entry. A 1:N User -> Rights relation. Instead of using the value `write` as right (whats the difference between add and write anyways) you should use an identifier and maybe match it with another table or enum in your applikation.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57904/mysql-split-value-in-column-to-get-multiple-rows